# Linear algebra equation with swapped unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following linear equation

$A X + X B = C$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, are known real $n \times n$ square matrices, and where $X$ is an unknown real $n \times n$ square matrix.  I want to have an analytical expression for the matrix $X$ that solves the above linear problem.

Comment: What you have there is a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: Which you can solve in Matlab via `X = lyap(A,B,C) `

Comment: But should you need to write your own solver: see [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/361573.361582) and [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/Hessenberg.Schur.Method.pdf).

Comment: @ J.M.: thank you for the references.  I was looking for a analytical solution, but from what I see that does exist in simple form (not at least one where X is not reshaped in vector form).

Comment: Yeah, you'll need the Kronecker product and the $\mathrm{vec}$ operator for an "analytical solution".

Answer (score 2):

What I have in a course of mine is a formula for the solution of the problem $AX-XB=C$ with $\sigma(A)\cap \sigma(B)=\emptyset$ and $A,B,C$ operators on the same Banach space. $R(\lambda;A)=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$, etc.

The solution has the formula

$$X=-\frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\Gamma_1} \int_{\Gamma_2}\frac{R(\lambda;A)CR(\mu;B)}{\lambda-\mu}d\mu d\lambda $$

Where $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ are contours which contain $\sigma(A),\sigma(B)$, respectively.

I remember checking this once using functional calculus, but I don't know if I can still do it now. :)

Comment: This looks interesting, I would like to read more about this. Do you have any reference suggestions?

Comment: You can find more details in Dunford, Schwarz, Linear operators Part I, starting from page 566.

Answer (score 0):

I knew there was this article. [This](http://lsc.amss.ac.cn/~dcheng/files/J149.pdf) can be an alternative way that you want. Still don't know why you don't prefer the mainstream method, but you can give it a shot.